# How to merge multiple parquet files in Glue

Tags: pandas, boto3, aws-glue, pyarrow

I have Glue job which is writing parquet files in S3 every 6 seconds and S3 is having folder for that hour. At the end of the hour I want to merge all the files in that hour partition then put it in the same location. I don't want to use the Athena tables because job becomes slow. I am trying using Python Shell. But so for I have not found correct solution. Can someone help me with this?

File is also snappy zipped

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your Parquet files are, and what the target size is – here's an idea to do this without Glue:

1. Set up an hourly Cloudwatch cron rule to look in the directory of the previous file to invoke a Lambda function.
2. Open each Parquet file, and write them to a new parquet file.
3. Write the resulting Parquet file to the S3 key and remove the parts.

Note there are some limitations/considerations with this design:

1. Your Parquet files need to stay within the limits of your Lambda's memory capacity. If you aim for getting to parts that are 128mb, you should be able to achieve this
2. Your separate Parquet schemas need to be identical for you to be reliably "merging" them. If they are not, you need to look into the Parquet file's metadata footer which contains the schema to ensure the schema has the metadata for all the column chunks.
3. Because the S3 operation is not atomic, you may have a brief moment in which the new S3 Parquet object is uploaded but the old ones haven't been removed. If you don't require to query it within this window, that shouldn't be a problem.

If you require Glue specifically, you may be able to just invoke a Glue job from the Lambda as opposed to trying to do it yourself from within Lambda.